# Насильно или насильственно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика

Грамотно ли сказать: "В доме меня держат *насильственно*"?

Согласно Викисловарю "насильственно" означает *против воли; путем насилия, принуждения*.
Такое же определение дано и для слова "насильно". Выходит, можно так и так употреблять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из словаря:

НАСИЛЬНО, нареч. Против воли, желания; силой. Н. выдать замуж. Н. увезти из города. * Насильно мил не будешь (Погов.).

НАСИЛЬСТВЕННЫЙ,  1. Осуществляемый путём насилия, принуждения. Прибегнуть к насильственным мерам. Н-ая депортация коренного населения. Н-ая смерть (убийство). 2. Производимый против воли, желания. Н. смех. Н-ая улыбка. <Насильственно, нареч. Н. улыбаться. Принудить н. Насильственность, -и; ж.

НАСИЛИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Применение **грубой физической силы или морального давления**. Применить н. при задержании преступника. Со следами насилия на лице. Н. над личностью. Избавление от произвола и насилия.

Судя по словарю, наречие "насильственно" может быть свзано с   более жесткими действиями, поэтому смысловое различие есть, и его лучше учитывать.

**В доме меня держат насильно.** Против воли и желания.

**В доме меня держат насильственно**. Возможно, взаперти,  с применением грубой силы.

Answer (score -1):

В данном конкретном случае правильно сказать - насильно.
Насильственно может выдать ответ только гугл-переводчик. ))